# Maximize sum of squares

Tags: optimization, sums-of-squares

Lets say that I know that $n$ values $x_i$ sums up to $\mu$:
$$
\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i
$$
 I also now that $0\leq x_i\leq 1$ for all $i=1\cdots n$.

I want to find an upper bound as tight as possible for the sum of their squares $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ as a function of $\mu$ and $n$.

I know that in general $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2=\mu^2$, but in this case if $\mu=n$ because of the costraints it results $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=n=\mu<\mu^2=n^2$ which is too loose for what I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want as many of the $x_i$ to be $1$ as possible.  If you have $0 \lt x_1,x_2 \lt 1$ you can increase $x_1^2+x_2^2$ by increasing the larger and decreasing the smaller.  So the maximum sum of squares will be $\lfloor \mu \rfloor + (\mu-\lfloor \mu \rfloor)^2$ as long as $\mu \lt n$.  If $\mu \gt n$ there is no solution.

Comment: It was super simple, thank you!